# Is there a way to write A > C or B > C as (A or B) > C?

Tags: python, syntax

Is there a way to write

```
return a > c or b > c
```

As

```
return (a or b) > c
```

?
Thank you!

Comment: `a > c or b > c` is perfect code, keep it as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you propose doesn't work.  I don't know why you find the first statement deficient, but here's an alternative:

```
return max(a, b) > c
```

Comment: My AI teacher has a thing for the shortest code possible

Comment: @PearsonFrank your teacher is misguided.  You should strive for clearness over brevity.

Comment: I am well aware, his theory is that brevity can be graded and if you can make it short you can make it long

Comment: @PearsonFrank this is a mistake that is made constantly - just because something is easy to measure doesn't mean that measuring it is a good idea.  Feel free to tell your teacher that some random guy on the internet thinks he's an idiot.

Answer (score 2):

Try [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

```
return max(a,b) > c
```